# Family of sets, intersection of disks

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am working with the following family of sets
$$A_t = \{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R^2}: \exists \ s \in\mathbb{R} \ [(x-s)^2 + (y-t)^2 \le t^2]\}, t \in \mathbb{R}$$
I am trying to find ${\bigcap_{t>0}{A_t}}$. I have noticed this is basically an equation of a disk with the center in $(s,t)$ and a radius $t$. My intuition is that:

1. For a specific $t$, the family is actually $\{(x,y): 0 \le y \le 2t\}$, so a part of the $\mathbb{R^2}$ plane limited by the x axis and $y = 2t$.
2. Letting $t$ vary we have a family of sets with the common element being $y = 0$ - the x-axis.

I would appreciate any comments or hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $A_t = \mathbb{R} \times [0,2t]$. Then the intersection is just
$\cap_t A_t = \mathbb{R} \times \{0\}$.

Comment: It is the same whether you have $t>0$ or $t \ge 0$. Just as $\cap_{t >0} [0,t] = \cap_{t \ge0} [0,t] = \{0\}$.